# Doing multiple fetch not working React native

Tags: react-native, fetch

I'm doing a network scanner in react-native,

The problem is my api request are working but not in the for loop,
if I just made a for loop with 30loop its ok, but if I got more than 30loops
nothing is working.

if the IP to find is 192.168.1.79
and I set num_two to 60 and num_one to 1, this work good.
But if I set num_two to 50 and num_one to 1, this isn't working anymore.

My searching function:

```
searchInNetwork(net) {
    return new Promise(async (resolve, reject) => {
        for (let num_one = 1 ; num_one < 255 ; num_one++) {
            let reseau = net + String(num_one);
            for (let num_two = 50 ; num_two < 255 ; num_two++) {
                let url = 'http://' + reseau + '.' + String(num_two) + ':3000/connect';
                await ApiService.getRequest(url, 100)
                    .then((data) => {
                        console.log("SUCCESS");
                        ApiService.url = 'http://' + reseau + '.' + String(num_two) + ':3000';
                        ApiService.connected = true;
                        resolve();
                    })
`                   .catch((error) => {
                        if (url === "http://192.168.1.79:3000/connect")
                            console.log(error);
                    })
            }
        }
    });
}
```

My ApiService class:

```
class ApiService {
    static url = 'http://0.0.0.0:3000';
    static connected = false;

    static getUrl() {
        return (this.url);
    }

    static getRequest(route, timeout) {
        return new Promise(async (resolve, reject) => {
            fetch(route)
                .then((response) => response.json())
                .then((responseJson) => {
                    ApiService.connected = true;
                    resolve(responseJson);
                })
                .catch((error) => {
                    ApiService.connected = false;
                    reject(error);
                });
            if (timeout) {
                const error = new Error("Timeout net");
                setTimeout(reject, timeout, error);
            }
        });
    };
};

module.exports = ApiService;
```